# Delta lake with Glue Catalog as metastore

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, delta-lake

We are using Spark (v3.3.0) SQL to consume data from a delta lake (v2.2.0), running on top of S3. The Spark jobs are run using Glue jobs and also EMR cluster. We want our code to refer to the delta tables through a metastore so that the codebase doesn’t need to reference the S3 bucket physically and keep the tables & partitions abstracted away from their physical path that might be subject to change. We are able to achieve this by creating a Glue data catalog and referencing the same via Glue context in the Spark consumer.

**code snippet without using any metastore:**

```
s3_path = "s3a://bucketprefix-prod/bucketname/"

(spark.read.format('delta').load(f"{s3_path}table_name/")      
.createOrReplaceTempView('table_name')) 
spark.sql("select * from table_name limit 10").show();
```

**code snippet using Glue Catalog as metastore:**

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
 database = "myDB",
 table_name = "table_name")
datasource0.show(10);
```

Else, I can directly write this also -

```
spark.sql("USE `mydatabase`")
spark.sql('select * from table_name limit 10').show()
```

Glue Catalog as the metastore however introduces an additional step of re-running the Glue crawler every time any of the delta tables get updated, otherwise the catalog doesn't include the latest data. Does this mean the crawler needs to be invoked programatically to update the catalog after every update iteration?

While we do see the value of having a metastore but, the extra step of running the crawler after every incremental batch seems to be an unnecessary step. Can the delta log, that gets auto updated with each incremental write, not be used by the metastore internally to reflect the updated data, without having to rerun the crawler?

We are a bit new to this space and maybe are missing something conceptually here. Please clarify if there's any flaw / missing link in our understanding and how best can the need of having a metastore be incorporated, that will not expose the physical bucket link / partition info within the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the table with the following command:

```py
my_df = spark.read.table("my_table")
```

And update the table with the [Delta Library](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#language-python) once your transformations are done.